# Когда AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() без параметров возвращает false?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть несколько перегрузок `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()`
Когда срабатывает сигнал `signal.Set()`, метод `WaitOne()` во всех перегрузках возвращает `true`.
В перегрузке с таймаутом `signal.WaitOne(timeout)` возвращает `false` когда таймаут истечет.

А что с перегрузкой без параметров `signal.WaitOne()`?
Она может возвращать только `true` и никогда `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WaitOne()` вызывает другую перегрузку:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/waithandle.cs,212

```
public virtual bool WaitOne ()
{
    //Infinite Timeout
    return  WaitOne(-1,false);
}
```

Дальше идет вызов статического метода `InternalWaitOne`:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/waithandle.cs,235

```
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
internal static bool InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext)
{
    if (waitableSafeHandle == null)
    {
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(null, Environment.GetResourceString("ObjectDisposed_Generic"));
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    int ret = WaitOneNative(waitableSafeHandle, (uint)millisecondsTimeout, hasThreadAffinity, exitContext);

    if(AppDomainPauseManager.IsPaused)
        AppDomainPauseManager.ResumeEvent.WaitOneWithoutFAS();

    if (ret == WAIT_ABANDONED)
    {
        ThrowAbandonedMutexException();
    }
    return (ret != WaitTimeout);
}
```

`WaitOneNative` потом вызывает функцию WinAPI `WaitForSingleObjectEx`. Так что `WaitOne` без параметров или возвратит `true`, или кинет `AbandonedMutexException`. Так как `WaitForSingleObjectEx` не может вернуть статус `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, если указан бесконечный таймаут.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobjectex